# How to retrieve certain resourcename in a section created in another section of JSON?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

How does this work in JSON ARM templates?

```json
"CopyUniqueNameToArmParameters": [
  "vmName"
]
```

I am working with ARM template where in one section where ARM template to create virtual machine is getting called. and in that section above snippet is being used. Now in another section I need to use his vmName but not sure how it is deciding the VMName and how to retrieve it for next section.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code example, it's not clear to me what the problem context is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CopyUniqueNameToArmParameters` is a custom function that copies a resource's unique name to an ARM parameter.

In your case, it copies the virtual machine's name to an ARM parameter called `VMName`. In another section, you can get the value of `VMName` by referencing the parameter name.

To retrieve the `VMName`, use the below syntax:

```bash
resources:[
{ 
     "name": "[parameters('VMName')]"
 }
 ]
```

*Note:* The `VMName` is supplied as a parameter to the resource that requires it.

The value passed to `CopyUniqueNameToArmParameters` is the name of the ARM template parameter that will store the unique name. The unique name is copied to the `VMName` parameter in the given scenario.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/user-defined-functions) for more relevant information.